# Fill missing coumns in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

There are lots of questions about filling missing values.

I want to fill whole missing columns.

Suppose I have:

`df=pd.DataFrame([1,2], columns=['A'])`

```
   A
0  1
1  2
```

What's the idiomatic way to do something like this?

`df.fillmissing(['A','B','C'])`

My current code:

```
for name in colnames:
    if name not in df:
        df[name] = None
```

This produces:

```
   A   B   C
0  1 NaN NaN
1  2 NaN NaN
```

Explanation of output:

In this case `A` is a no-op, but `B` and `C` get added, i.e.:

- I don't know ahead of time which columns are missing
- I know which columns I want
- I want the most concise code (high performance is not a requirement)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you need `reindex`:

```
df.reindex(['A', 'B', 'C'], axis=1)

   A   B   C
0  1 NaN NaN
1  2 NaN NaN
```

This fills missing columns with NaN, leaving existing columns as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try transposing it then `reindex` it:

```
print(df.T.reindex(['A', 'B', 'C']).T)
```

Comment: This is two extra operations to avoid a single argument, a bit strange, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following dataframe `df` and lookup columns `cols`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([1,2], columns=['A'])
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

From there, you can subtract the list of the columns from the dataframe from the list of columns from `cols` and create the new columns all at once (that don't exist after subtraction) and set to `None`. Note: You cannot directly subtract lists from each other unless you convert to a `set` first. Then, enclose `[*]` around the set to transform to a list:

**Method 1: Set Subtraction**

```
df[[*set(cols) - set(df.columns)]] = None
df
Out[1]: 
   A     B     C
0  1  None  None
1  2  None  None
```

The list comprehension way would be:

**Method 2: List Comprehension (similar to your for loop)**

```
df[[col for col in cols if col not in df.columns]] = None
df
Out[1]: 
   A     B     C
0  1  None  None
1  2  None  None
```